# Safely Increase Size of Door Bolt?

Tags: door

I live in an apartment right near the garage of the apartment. Every time someone comes in or out of the garage, the change in air pressure causes my door to slam a bit and it sounds like someone is trying to break into my apartment (spoiler alert, they're not).

This bothers me and I haven't found a great way to fix it. I feel like the issue is that the bolt in my door is too small (either that, or the piece of the door that retracts when you turn the knob [I have no idea what it's called] is too small). I'm wondering if you guys had any clever ideas for how I might stop my door from slamming every time the air pressure changes? It's really annoying!

Comment: This is a very common problem in apartment living, and I'm sure they have a tried-and-true way of fixing this on our **[Home Improvement site](http://diy.stackexchange.com)**. This may seem like it needs a "hack", but it is a very common problem making sure the door is fitted and framed properly. Best to ask the experts there.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I would add some weatherseal/foam strip to the door to prevent the hard parts from coming in contact and dampening the motion with the increased pre-load on the door. This seems like a life hack to me.

Comment: What I ended up doing to solve this (as suggested by one of the guys in Home Improvement, [link](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68488/safely-increase-size-of-door-bolt)) was to add small little felt pads (round furniture sliders, actually) into the slots where the door jamb and bolt enter, to make it a tighter fit. I actually cut the round felt pads in half, so that they fit better. So it was kind of a life hack after all, lol.